# Difference function in SSRS

Tags: ssrs

I have a a column of dollar amounts that I want to calculate the running difference (opposite of sum() ? ) of. Does Reporting services have a diff function or something way that I can do a running difference on a column?

Example dataset:

```
Year  |    amt   | pts
2007  |  1500    | 0
2008  |  1200    | 10
2009  |  1800    | 0
```

what I'm looking to do is take a running difference of the amt column and another for the pts column. Something to get me to...

```
amt = -1500     // (1500 - 1200 - 1800) 
pts = -10       // ( 0 - 10 - 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use an expression for the total that would look like this:

```
=SUM(iif(Fields!Year.Value = MIN(Fields!Year.Value, "YourDataset"),Fields!Dollar.value,-1*Fields!Dollar.value))
```